# Include view in base template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm making a simple blog app and i want to have blog categories in the navbar which is in every page of the website.

do i have to pass a `categories = Category.objects.all()` object to EVERY view or is there any simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, look at [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext):

**myapp/context_processors.py**

```
def categories(request):
    return {'categories': Category.objects.all()}
```

And then add this to the [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) setting:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    "myapp.context_processors.categories",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is simpler solution, you can use [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS). Simply create in your app file named context_processors (name of that file doesn't matter, but good practice is to name it that way) and inside that file create any function that will take request argument and return dictionary with additional context variables. Example:

```
from .models import Category

def categories(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    return {
        'categories': categories,
    }
```

Now simply add your context processor into settings:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (
    'yourapp.context_processors.categories',
)
```